# Refactor Doctrine DQL/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities `User` and `Email`, where a user can have multiple emails where only one can be a main email.

I want to know if there is a DQL query to select the main email if exists otherwise it select to first non-main email.

The output should be like this:

```
[
   [user_id:1, email: 'main@email.com'],
   [user_id:2, email: 'not-main@email.com'],
]
```

Thanks in advance.

```
class User 
{ 
    /** @OneToMany */
    protected $emails;
}

class Email 
{
    /** @boolean */
    protected $isMain = 0;

    /** @ManyToOne */
    protected $user;
}
```

The existing solution that I'm trying to convert to a DQL:

```
public function getMainEmail(): ?string
{
    $emails = $this->getEmails();

    if (empty($emails) || 0 === \count($emails)) {
        return null;
    }

    /** @var Email $email */
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if (1 === $email->getMain()) {
            return $email->getEmail();
        }
    }

    return $emails->first()->getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the kind of solution you are looking for, because it actually doesn't use DQL: You could order the associated collection by your `isMain` flag.

```
class User 
{ 
    /** 
    * @OneToMany 
    * @OrderBy({"isMain" = "DESC"})
    */
    protected $emails;
}
```

Calling `$emails->first()` would then always return the users main address, if there is one with the main flag.

See also:

Comment: hey @simon.ro thanks for the tips, this will help me refactor my code, i didn't know about the `@OrderBy`